# How to find cycle from autocorrelation?

Tags: matlab, autocorrelation

I have an ECG data set of length 3380. It provides a cyclic plot diagram like this
[image: plot diagram]

and autocorrelation diagram like this
[image: auto correlation]

I am saying that the data set provides cyclic behavior. How can I prove that the data set provides cycle using auto correlation.
Here is my Matlab code:

```
[raw] = xlsread(fullfile(matlabroot, 'acf', 'ecg.xlsx'));
Y = raw;
plot(Y);
autocorr(Y);
```

And here is my dataset 
[ecg.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4j0qSBRPzUQMThZaDY2QUlWUUE)

My question is how can I say that the data set is periodic/cyclic from the autocorrelation result?

Comment: Can you please give few lines of your data here instead of excel file link to the google drive?

Comment: first 20 lines are like this
2.057700855
2.006533043
1.958357038
1.908049953
1.858659319
1.807375486
1.75720657
1.705486038
1.656331737
1.601486202
1.519816621
1.431730868
1.346599018
1.25782131
1.172396771
1.079935755
1.018148684
1.006441687
0.991469272
0.985787001